# Can I send an Ampersand late?

Tags: terminal

I regularly type something like

> open .

or

> nautilus /examples/

and then kick myself because I really wanted to write:

> open .  &

or

> nautilus /examples/ &

Is there some key combination that lets me send the & late and get control of my terminal back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `bash` as shell, you could press `Ctrl+Z` in the terminal to put the program in the background **paused**. Follow by `bg` to have it **running** in the background.
If you want to close the terminal window and still have it running, you might use `disown`.

Comment: Tested and works.  Thank you.